# Where is the # key in Vim Adventures?

Tags: vim-adventures

I'm at the space abyss where bugs ate a hole in the universe and the tip is to use <kbd>*</kbd> and <kbd>#</kbd>, but I can't find <kbd>#</kbd>.
[image: screenshot of my current location]

Comment: What level is it?

Comment: I'm on level 8, but I may have missed it along the way.

Comment: Ah. It looks like a cool game/learning tool. In trying to help, I did the 3 tutorial levels that are free but I hit a paywall, so I wasn't able to get to where you are. Hopefully someone else can help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't missed the # key.

Use the * key to navigate past the puzzle below your screenshot.  The # key is hiding in a bush.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't get that to work before. Maybe I was just lead astray by the pink haired girl's mention of the #